# golang copy function understanding

Tags: go

Hey guys I was playing around with some buffers and I just wrote some code to understand how Read() works

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
)

func main() {
    tmp := make([]byte, 2)
    data := []byte("HEL")

    dataReader := bytes.NewReader(data)
    dest := make([]byte, len(data))
    for {
        n, err := dataReader.Read(tmp)
        fmt.Println(n)
        fmt.Println(string(tmp))
        dest = append(dest, tmp[:]...)
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(string(dest))
}
```

```
output:
2 -> n
HE -> tmp[:]
1 -> n
LE -> tmp[:]
0 -> n
LE -> tmp[:]
HELELE -> dest
```

So I know the output is wrong and I should actually be doing `temp[:n]` to write the bytes, but looking at the output I realised that the tmp buffer does not get cleared on every iteration, also when n is 1 should'nt the contents of the buffer be EL, I mean L is getting prepended to tmp not appended. I took a look at Read function but couldn't understand. Can someone explain it to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first iteration, `Read` reads two bytes, and your program produces the `HE` output. In the second iteration, `Read` reads one byte into `tmp`. Now `tmp[0]` contains that byte, but `tmp[1]` still contains the `E` read during the first iteration. However, you append all of `tmp` to `dest`, getting `HELE`. The third time around, read reads 0 bytes, but you still append the `LE` in `tmp` to `dest`.

The correct version of your program would be:

```
 for {
        n, err := dataReader.Read(tmp)
        fmt.Println(n)
        fmt.Println(string(tmp))
        dest = append(dest, tmp[:n]...)

        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
    }
```